# Firebase listing order by date in flutter not working

Tags: flutter, firebase

> I need to show list of documents in flutter , it should be show list by descending order of date
> and i need a filter a by where condition also, and it is not working both,
>
> if i add where condition only then it will work
> if i add orderby only then it also works
>
> but if i add where and orderby with diffrent data field, it is not working

here is the code snippet

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _productsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('projects')
      .where('status', whereIn: ['1', '2'])
      .orderBy('date', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
```

> but if i add where and orderby with diffrent data field, it is not working
>
> here is the code snippet

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _productsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('projects')
      .where('status', whereIn: ['1', '2'])
      .orderBy('date', descending: true)
      .snapshots();
```

Comment: Use the Firestore Query Builder to create the query, if it is ok it will perform the search, but if it needs indexing the query builder will suggest a link to create the indexed query.

Comment: Thanks, I found the link to create the index. thank you for helping

Comment: Now that I saw that I didn't specify the reason, queries with where/order sometimes need to be indexed, hence the need to test the query in Firestore's query builder and check the need for index. I'm glad you understood what I said.